# prove optimality only by cutting without branching (gurobi)

Tags: mixed-integer-programming

I have a MIP which I know the solution almost for certain. I want to use gurobi to prove that the true solution (even if it is not the one i provide) shall not lie more than 0.5% deviated from the solution I gave. I believe that simply keep cutting without branching would possibly save much more time. Do you know a way that I could simply do cutting without branching in gurobi? thank you!

Here's the code performance:

```
Changed value of parameter LogFile to 
   Prev: gurobi.log   Default: 

Changed value of parameter MIPFocus to 3
   Prev: 0   Min: 0   Max: 3   Default: 0

Changed value of parameter Cuts to 3
   Prev: -1   Min: -1   Max: 3   Default: -1

Optimize a model with 1794 rows, 673 columns and 4180 non zeros

Found heuristic solution: objective -22.8549

Presolve removed 18 rows and 17 columns
Presolve time: 0.01s
Presolved: 1776 rows, 656 columns, 4464 nonzeros

Loaded MIP start with objective -342.641

Variable types: 592 continuous, 64 integer (64 binary)
Presolved: 1776 rows, 656 columns, 4464 nonzeros

Root relaxation: objective -6.775689e+02, 682 iterations, 0.02 seconds

    Nodes    |    Current Node    |     Objective Bounds      |     Work
 Expl Unexpl |  Obj  Depth IntInf | Incumbent    BestBd   Gap | It/Node Time

     0     0 -677.56892    0   64 -342.64109 -677.56892  97.7%     -    0s
     0     0 -666.45290    0   72 -342.64109 -666.45290  94.5%     -    0s
     0     0 -658.68050    0   72 -342.64109 -658.68050  92.2%     -    1s
     0     0 -540.92023    0   72 -342.64109 -540.92023  57.9%     -    3s
     0     0 -503.36031    0   72 -342.64109 -503.36031  46.9%     -    4s
     0     0 -485.13025    0   72 -342.64109 -485.13025  41.6%     -    6s
     0     0 -472.73790    0   72 -342.64109 -472.73790  38.0%     -    8s
     0     0 -461.23185    0   72 -342.64109 -461.23185  34.6%     -    9s
     0     0 -453.99476    0   72 -342.64109 -453.99476  32.5%     -   10s
     0     0 -452.23014    0   72 -342.64109 -452.23014  32.0%     -   10s
     0     3 -452.23014    0   72 -342.64109 -452.23014  32.0%     -   11s
   642   586 -397.07656   12   54 -342.64109 -429.76289  25.4%   120   15s
  1425  1290 -397.34606   11   60 -342.64109 -422.53417  23.3%   114   20s
  1716  1553 -382.83438   18   72 -342.64109 -420.42709  22.7%   111   25s
  1727  1560 -376.17473   16   72 -342.64109 -420.42709  22.7%   110   30s
  1733  1564 -410.28764   10   72 -342.64109 -420.42709  22.7%   110   35s
  1744  1571 -382.83438   18   72 -342.64109 -420.42709  22.7%   109   40s
  1750  1577 -412.59771   12   69 -342.64109 -416.84728  21.7%   113   45s
  1817  1602 -380.32997   19   60 -342.64109 -404.73090  18.1%   120   50s
  2618  2045 -375.99924   18   62 -342.64109 -391.32863  14.2%   126   55s
  3159  2315 -369.40052   22   59 -342.64109 -386.33088  12.8%   127   60s
  3808  2595 -362.27693   20   60 -342.64109 -382.29310  11.6%   127   65s
  4503  2903 -350.90325   24   54 -342.64109 -379.52932  10.8%   126   71s
  4895  3078 -349.90847   23   55 -342.64109 -378.33598  10.4%   126   78s
  5339  3242 -363.26836   21   59 -342.64109 -376.77299  10.0%   126   80s
  6421  3664 -366.32746   21   56 -342.64109 -374.20072  9.21%   126   85s
  7560  4450 -357.93456   21   59 -342.64109 -371.61876  8.46%   126   90s
  8849  5297 -355.57657   21   59 -342.64109 -369.33074  7.79%   125   95s
 10004  6042 -357.02223   24   55 -342.64109 -367.63772  7.30%   124  100s
 11274  6819 -352.14570   23   55 -342.64109 -365.95440  6.80%   122  105s
 12362  7437 -357.95155   22   55 -342.64109 -364.73335  6.45%   122  110s
 13134  7882 -352.18831   25   47 -342.64109 -363.91508  6.21%   121  115s
 ...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think it's possible, from looking at the [list of controllable attributes on Gurobi's website](http://www.gurobi.com/documentation/5.6/reference-manual/attributes), and the [list of controllable attributes on Gurobi's website](http://www.gurobi.com/documentation/5.6/reference-manual/parameters). You can turn off cuts, but not branching, probably because branch-and-bound will still yield a convergent algorithm, whereas I'm not aware of a general purpose mixed-integer linear programming algorithm that only cuts. Cuts also make your LP relaxations bigger, whereas branching (without cutting) makes the smaller, at the cost of adding subproblems.

You might instead try supplying a good initial guess (if you know one; your question suggests you do) and then use Gurobi's parameter tuning heuristics as a first pass. The information from the tuning heuristics could then inform better choices of parameters that control branching direction (and variable choice) and cut selection.